# Stochastic differential equations and experimental data

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-calculus

If we have a set of experimental data: 
$$X=\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_N\}$$
is it possible to write down an equation of the kind:
$$dx(t)=b(x(t))\,dt+\sigma(x(t))\,dB(t)$$
describing the process from which the data arise,
in which $B(t)$ is a Brownian process, $b$ is a function of only $x(t)$ and $\sigma$ the standard deviation? In which cases is it impossible?

Thanks.

Comment: Does each $x$ value have a corresponding $t$ value?

Comment: @ Michael Hardy: Yes, you get every $x_k$ at time $t_k$

Comment: ....and are those values of $t$ a part of the observable data?

Comment: @ Michael Hardy: yes they are...

Comment: That should be mentioned in the question.  Without the $t$ values, I doubt that much can be done.

Comment: Since you have only finitely many data points and an infinite-dimensional space of possible functions $b$, and the data, even if improbably, could emerge from a process with almost any values of $b$ and $\sigma$, I think what you need is statistical estimation rather than trying to find some unique solution.  And at this point I think you would fare better at stats.stackexchange.com, and there you should mention that you observe pairs $(t_i,x_i),\  i=1,\ldots,N$, and that you want to estimate $b$ and $\sigma$.